# How to list the content of a named volume in docker 1.9+?

Tags: docker

Docker 1.9 added named volumes, so I..

```
docker volume create --name postgres-data

docker volume ls
```

and I get

```
local               postgres-data
```

all good so far..

so how do I see what is in the named volume?  Is there a way to cd to it on the host system.  Like I can for a mounted host directory?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

```
docker run --rm -i -v=postgres-data:/tmp/myvolume busybox find /tmp/myvolume
```

Explanation: Create a minimal container with tools to see the volume's files (busybox), mount the named volume on a container's directory (`v=postgres-data:/tmp/myvolume`), list the volume's files (`find /tmp/myvolume`). Remove the container when the listing is done (`--rm`).

Comment: It's a good answer, but I don't like that it requires creation of another container to look at the filesystem of a container.  The first answer avoids this.

Comment: The first answer didn't work for me.  Directory didn't exist there.  This answer worked.

Comment: View my answer below to see why you can't access the path if you're on Mac or Windows.

Comment: I am not sure accepted answer really is the answer. So far I have found if the driver is "local" you probably cannot read the content on the host. As mentioned in this answer, you are required to mount the volume to a container to read it.

Comment: Use [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) if you are confined to localhost. Else you would have to use different driver to do a volume mount.

Comment: This answer also works for podman. The folder `MountPoint` points to does not exist in host machine. Perhaps it's in VM.

Answer (score 67):

you can run 
`docker volume inspect postgres-data`

and see `Mountpoint` section of the result

therefore source parameter will point to host directory 
maybe
`/var/lib/docker/volumes/[volume_name]/_data` directory

Comment: Did you try to run your written command? I doubt it will work as you must pass a volume hash instead of container's name. You can get list of volumes with `docker volume ls`

Comment: @vaidasniedu02@ubuntu:~/assistant$ docker volume inspect postgres-data`
    [
       {
            "Name": "postgres-data",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/postgres-data/_data"
        }
     ]

Comment: yeah, it works for a _named_ _volume_, this was a new feature added in docker 1.9.  I think your answer is for a _named_ _container_, not a named volume.  Test it and update the answer so i can mark your answer correct.

Comment: In Mac, you need extra steps: https://gist.github.com/BretFisher/5e1a0c7bcca4c735e716abf62afad389#gistcomment-3398964

Answer (score 47):

You can see where docker is storing a volume by running `docker volume inspect <volume>`.

But there's a caveat: You can't directly see the contents of volumes on Mac and Windows.
This occurs because Docker actually runs a Linux VM to be able to containerize, since containzerzation is native functionality for Linux but not these others OSes. So the path that appears is actually the path inside the VM, and not on your host system.

You can access these volumes by using the methods mentioned in the other answers (create a ephemeral container just to view the content) or you can access these directly.

### For Mac

For Mac, you can use `screen` to get access to the VM, like so:

```
# This path can be slightly different on your system
screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty
```

And once there, you can navigate to the path that `docker volume inspect` gave you.

### For Windows

With Docker Desktop & WSL2

Navigate to `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes` in Windows Explorer

Comment: On Windows 10, using Docker Desktop and WSL2, you can go to `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes` in Windows Explorer.

Comment: awesome comment above - on Windows git bash you can cd to it with ... cd //wsl$/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data/community/docker/volumes

Comment: @RodneyRichardson You should make that a top-level answer.

Comment: There is [an issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4822) with docker mac screen. The 2022 workaround is to start a priviledged container `docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host alpine:edge nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh` (you should find volumes in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`)

Comment: @RodneyRichardson The updated path is ```\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes\```.

Answer (score 13):

Or **no need** for **jq** or the **new container**.

**`cd` to the directory:**

```
cd $(docker volume inspect <volume name> | grep Mountpoint | cut -d\" -f 4)
```

**View the content of the directory:**

```
ls -las $(docker volume inspect <volume name> | grep Mountpoint | cut -d\" -f 4)
```

**Even better!** View the content of all volumes:

```
for i in  `docker volume ls -q`; do echo volume: ${i}; \
ls -las $(docker volume inspect $i | grep Mountpoint | cut -d\" -f 4); \
done
```

Using it all the time, when need to find something quickly.

Comment: Very elegant. I admire your ability to memorize this one-liner... :-)

Answer (score 12):

Here's one idea...

```
docker run -it --name admin -v postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data ubuntu
```

then in the interactive shell

```
ls /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Better ideas welcome!

Comment: For those who are trying to access a local NAMED volume on WINDOWS the command is:

`winpty docker run -it --name admin -v postgres-data://var//lib//postgresql//data ubuntu`

Notice the `winpty` prefix AND double slashes to avoid GitBash for Windows mischieves

Answer (score 7):

With *`jq`:

```
$ sudo ls -l $(docker volume inspect VOLUME_NAME | jq -r '.[0].Mountpoint')
```

*Check [jq doc page](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) for details on how to install it if not yet (`PACKAGE_MANAGER install jq`).

Answer (score 6):

I use this handy function to list the content of my volumes:

```
dvolume() {
  local volume volumes_to_list=${1:-$(docker volume ls --quiet)}
  for volume in $volumes_to_list; do
    sudo ls -lRa "$(docker volume inspect --format '{{ .Mountpoint }}' "$volume")"
    echo
  done
}
```

Notice you can call the function in two ways:

```
$ dvolume           # for each volume, list its content
$ dvolume <volume>  # list <volume>'s content
```

Comment: I wouldn't use this methodology, I believe this may causes some of the volume file permissions to get mutated in a bad state. It corrupted a volume I was working on

Comment: I would really like to know more details about the problem you talk about. Thanks.

Comment: @StanleyZheng How could the volume's file permissions get changed if the provided shell script is only listing directories contents?